# C# file.copy from network path fails could not find file

Tags: c#, .net

this is so simple its driving me crazy. i have another C# project where i had issues, so i then wrote a small windows form with a button that just copies a file.

```
File.Copy(@"\\host2\c$\test.txt", @"c:\test.txt");
```

i even tried

```
File.Copy(@"\\host2\c$\test.txt", @"\\localhost\test.txt");
```

each time it fails with exception `could not find file "\\host2\c$\test.txt"`

both hosts are win2008 in the same windows domain, i am domain admin with local admin rights on both hosts. i can do it from command line fine, and i can start/run to host name in windows find and copy also.

i am at a loss here? i googled around and lots of people had issues when one host was in domain in one in a workgroup, but that is not the case with my issue.

any help or ideas?

Comment: @SLaks - that edit makes your answer confusing...

Comment: I edited after answering and didn't actually notice the backslashes.  (the Markdown parser had swallowed them)  My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Can you manually get to that link through Windows Explorer? Any chance the default Windows share (C$) is disabled?

Comment: As in yes you can get there and yes it is disabled? Or do you mean yes and no ;)

Comment: sorry yes and no (it's enabled) ;), sorry multi tasking

Answer (score 1):

No reason in the world why that code won't work.

I know you've said you can do it in a command line, but I suspect the problem is still something to do with either permissions or shares.  Try starting your app as administrator, see if that helps

Comment: check the machines event logs to see if any errors are being displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling UAC remote restrictions on remote host
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016/